# ERROR: 2.0+ Platforms require a service role. You can provide one with --service-role option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ec2

We recently upgraded the EB CLI tool to version to 3.6.2 (Python 2.7.6).

Now when we spin up a new eb environment...

```
eb create dev-env -p "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.4 running Ruby 2.2 (Puma)" --single -i t2.micro --envvars SECRET_KEY_BASE=g5dh9cg61...
```

...we get this new error:

```
EB ERROR: 2.0+ Platforms require a service role. You can provide one with --service-role option
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EB CLI now requires you to specify a Service-Role.

If you dont already have one, create an 'aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role' role here: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#roles

1. Select the 'Amazon EC2' Aws Service roles type;
2. Assign one or more Permissions;
3. Update the Trust Relationships, paste in ( for example ):

   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Sid": "",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
           "Service": "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
         },
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
         "Condition": {
           "StringEquals": {
             "sts:ExternalId": "elasticbeanstalk"
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }

Now when you spin up the new EB environment, include the --service-role option :

```
eb create dev-env -p "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.4 running Ruby 2.2 (Puma)" --single -i t2.micro 
--service-role aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role --envvars SECRET_KEY_BASE=g5dh9cg614a37d4bd
```

Answer (score 2):

For other people wondering, there is an easier option: You can just run `eb create` again with no parameters and eb cli will take you through the steps to create a new --service-role (if you don't have one already).

> Note
>   In Windows, adding an .ebignore file causes the EB CLI to follow symbolic links and include the linked file when creating a source bundle. This is a known issue and will be fixed in a future update.

Reference: [Config of EB Cli - Aws website](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html)